# Graph Explorer - Add Guest to Team

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams

i have a problem to add guests to a team. I receive an 403 forbidden when i'm not the owner of a team.

i found similar issues with that like [Add Team Member via Graph API. Response: 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65221062/add-team-member-via-graph-api-response-403)

So here what i did:

- Graph Explorer has the Permission: **TeamMeber.ReadWrite.All** [delegated]
- My User has the role **Team Administrator**
- I have tested it with an **global administrator** as well

Request Uri: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/63b29ab5-6c63-4df1-b3fd-xxxx/members

Request Method: POST

Request Body:

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
    "roles": ["member"],
    "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('e4f6524f-4764-40a5-b5a3-xxxxxx')"
}
```

Is there something what i missed?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you succeed?